# How to calculate and plot time series residuals? (R or msexcel)

Tags: excel, r, time-series

I am working with yearly time series. The main purpose is to look at the trend over time. I plot the 'scatterplot' and then add the trendline(using MsExcell) in order to get the trendline. How could I calculate and plot the residuals? Thanks in advance.

```
1982    1983    1984    1985    1986    1987    1988    1989    1990    1991    1992    1993

27.75   28.74   28.13   28.07   28.68   28.83   28.93   28.59   28.18   28.65   28.54   28.79
27.84   28.71   28.34   28.08   28.66   28.91   28.90   28.63   28.21   28.63   28.58   28.89
29.81   29.32   29.64   29.51   29.25   29.67   29.90   29.10   29.79   29.73   29.92   30.23
28.24   29.34   28.03   28.66   28.95   29.48   29.40   28.91   29.09   28.59   28.86   28.90
```

Comment: The correct answer depends entirely on how you calculated the trendline.  "Using MS Excel" is not a formula for calculation.

Comment: This looks like quarterly data? Once you have transformed your data to 'long' format (one long vector), with an accompanying time vector (1982.0, 1982.25, 1982.5 ...) you could use `residuals(lm(y~time,data=mydata))`

Comment: Oh sorry...I left out an important indormation. Each rows actually represent different location. The data is actually temperature records.

Comment: The first and second rows of temperatures look suspiciously similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways of doing this.

One, using Excel 2007, is to

1. transpose your data so series are in columns
2. use "Data Analysis/Regression"
3. put one of the temperature series in the "Y range"
4. put the years series in the "X range"
5. choose a sensible "Output option"
6. ensure the "Residuals" and "Residual Plots" checkboxes are selected
7. select "OK"